# SharePoint 2010 & MySites & Remove 'Create Blog' link

Tags: my-site, blog

I have a SharePoint Server 2010 instance that has UPS setup and over 1000 end users using MySites. Is there a way to disable the 'Create Blog' link? Currently I have already deployed a custom master page, and what I'm looking is a solution that I could possibly resolve using CSS or a PowerShell script and I would like to avoid any server site code if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid server side code, then CSS through your custom master page is the way to go.

I [looked](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) at the [webpart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.portal.webcontrols.blogview.aspx) that renders the Create Blog link. The Create Blog link will always be shown to the My Site owner until a Blog site is created. Your only options are to hide the webpart through CSS or remove the webpart by manually editing the page or using server side code.

For more information, see [How can I disable the ability to create blogs in MySites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393490/sharepoint-2010-mysites-how-can-i-disable-the-ability-to-create-blogs-in-mysite)

Comment: See I thought the recommend and support apprach was to resolve this with a feature. I'll try it out and get back to you with an answer. Thanks again.